# English Language and Usage vs English Language Learners

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I can't believe that no one has ever asked this. I really want to find a duplication.

From "What topics can I ask about here?" of:

- [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (ELU):

> **Word choice and usage**
>   **Grammar**
>   Etymology (history of words’ development)
>   **Dialect differences**
>   Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
>   **Spelling and punctuation**

- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (ELL):

> **Word choice and usage**
>   **Grammar**
>   **Dialect differences**
>   **Spelling and punctuation**
>   Practical problems you encounter while learning English

You see, most of the questions in ELL can be covered in the ELU. Why don't we merge them into one? Just add the "Practical problems you encounter while learning English" topic to the ELU. Isn't the combination will make the site serve the community better? And where should I ask if I have a problem in the bold topics?

Comment: Isn't ELL for folks like me, non-native english speakers, and ELU for native speakers?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm a non-native speaker who have ask in ELU many times without meeting any problem.

Comment: @rene I'm a non-native English speaker, but I'd be more at home asking on ELU. Most of the questions I have about English could just as well be asked by a native speaker. If I ever formulated a question which I felt originates from the fact that English is not my mother tongue, then I guess I'd ask on ELL.

Comment: @Louis: even in that case, your questions still be suitable to ask in ELU.

Comment: There originally was one site, but the EL&U folks recognized that there were two audiences and worked to get ELL created. I'll see if I can dig up some source material.

Comment: This might be useful: [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3722)

Comment: And this: [How do I determine whether a question fits on English Language & Usage or on English Language Learners?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: And this, too: [Discussion on Area51 distinguishing English Language & Usage and English Language Learners](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/7945/drawing-the-lines-between-ell-and-elu)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: thank you so much. Finally I can get a answer. I just add a proposal to this as an answer. Can you check that for me?

Answer (score 9):

- ELL is effectively an English 101 site, definitely suitable for new learners of English, non-native speakers
- ELU is for more proficient users of English, native speakers, students of English

That's pretty much the way I view them.

Comment: Which doesn't really explain anything. From what I've seen, which questions belong on which site seem entirely arbitrary. People ask complex grammar questions on ELL (presumably because they are learning) but then since it's a complex grammar question, it should be on ELU. But then sometimes it turns out they DID ask it on ELU and got punted to ELL for no discernible reason. In the end, I looked up this question wondering what the difference was and after viewing several discussions, my conclusion is nobody really knows.

Comment: Interesting that is your perception. I see them as very different. Could be because I am a native speaker. "No discernible reason" is how you see it, but for the ELU community it is usually obvious. Usually.

Comment: I find it strange that they did this with the English site, yet every request to do it with [so] gets shut down extremely hard.

Answer (score 3):

This question is duplicated, as I expected. Thanks to Fish Below the Ice.

My proposal for this is changing the ELL guidance to this:

```
Basic word choice and usage 
Basic grammar
Basic dialect differences
Basic Spelling and punctuation
Practical problems you encounter while learning English
```

Comment: If you want to change the guidance of a particular site, you should post on that site's Meta.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have asked it here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/make-the-topics-to-ask-in-ell-clearer